# How to count the record of an object then display it in a field of same object?

Tags: apex

How to count all record of an object either standard or custom object then display the count to a field?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

**VF page :**

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <apex:outputText value="{!total}"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class myController {
    private Integer total;

    public Integer getTotal() {
        total = [SELECT count() FROM Account]; // Example for standard Account objects
        return total;
    }
}
```